# Writing an equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equation

For the following equation:

[image]

Do we write it in `MATLAB` as follows:

```
sum=0;
    for j=1:k
        for i=1:n
          sum = sum + (u(i,j)*log2(u(i,j)+(1-u(i,j)*log2(1-u(i,j)))))/n;  
        end
    end
    result = -1 * sum;
```

Thanks.

Comment: you seem to have i and j swapped around, is there a reason for this?

Comment: @Sionnach733: that is to make the **correct** answer to the question "no, that's not how we do it".

Answer (score 2):

**to quote Jongware:** *no, that's not how we do it!*

you rather write:

```
fun = @(x) x*log2(x)+(1-x)*log2(1-x);
result = -1/n*sum( arrayfun(fun,u(:)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would write that:

1. In Matlab we tend to avoid loops.
2. Considering the form of your equation, the two sums can be collapsed into one. In Matlab we can do that by using [linear indexing](http://www.mathworks.es/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).
3. Move the `n` out of the sum to reduce the number of operations.

So:

```
H = -sum(u(:).*log2(u(:))+(1-u(:)).*log2(1-u(:)))/n;
```

On the other hand, in your code:

1. You have some parentheses wrong. The computed value is not that given by the equation.
2. You should avoid using `i` and `j` as variable names, as they override the imaginary unit (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)).
3. You should avoid using `sum` as a variable name, as it overrides Matlab's bulit.in function `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum=0;
for i=1:k
    for j=1:n
      sum = sum + (u(i,j)*log2(u(i,j)+(1-u(i,j)*log2(1-u(i,j)))))/n;  
    end
end
result = -1 * sum;
```